# При установки Chocolatey для того что бы установить go на Windows Server мне кидают вот это

Tags: windows, chocolatey

WARNING: It's very likely you will need to close and reopen your shell
  before you can use choco.
Installation of Chocolatey to default folder requires Administrative permissions. Please run from elevat
ed prompt. Please see https://chocolatey.org/install for details and alternatives if needing to install
as a non-administrator.
C:\Users\Ирина\AppData\Local\Temp\chocolatey\chocInstall\tools\chocolateysetup.psm1:212 знак:5
+     throw "Installation of Chocolatey to default folder requires Admi ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Installation of...-administrator.:String) [], RuntimeE
   xception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Installation of Chocolatey to default folder requires Administrative perm
   issions. Please run from elevated prompt. Please see https://chocolatey.org/install for details and
   alternatives if needing to install as a non-administrator.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему вы не хотите установить *Go* согласно [официальной инструкции](https://golang.org/doc/install#windows)?

Comment: Я новичек в этом всем)
Как обычный User поперся гуглит и там по первым ссылкам)
Спасибо за наводку,щя попробую